# Xamarin Android : Https Post Request to Local Intranet Web Api Causes error : StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'

Tags: xamarin, encryption, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tls1.2

This is going to be a long question..

Our company has to follow [PCI Standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/), so a while back we had to ensure all our Servers were TLS1.2 compliant. As a result we implemented TLS as explained [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/securing-web-requests-with-tls-1-2/) in our Xamarin Forms app. But we noticed issues in Android versions less then Api 22. So we implemented a dependency service for fetching the HTTPClient and if the Api versions were less than 22 we implemented a custom ssl socket factory, [here's](https://gist.github.com/mshenoy83/9763e06d947db860c3305f6f59a62f3b) the example.

Everything was fine till a few weeks back there was a decision to upgrade the servers to Windows 2016 on the dev environment. We've redeployed our Web Api to the server and ever since then, the api is inaccessible from a few devices. The problem we've faced is in Samsung Galaxy S4(Android 4.4) and Nexus 5(Android 5.1.1). We've tried testing the app on a Samsung Galaxy A7(Android 6) and it works okay. iOS is also fine. 
This is the error we recieve on the S4 and Nexus 5

> StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2017
>   04:00:09 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-Android-Received-Millis:
>   1505880010792 X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 404
>   X-Android-Selected-Transport: http/1.1 X-Android-Sent-Millis:
>   1505880010781 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 1245 Content-Type:
>   text/html

Here's the signature of the Web Api

```
[HttpPost("GetMinimumVersion")]
public GetMinimumVersionResponse GetMinimumVersion([FromBody] GetMinimumVersionRequest value)
```

And this is the code we use to make a post request

```
using (_httpclient = _deviceInfo.GetHttpClient())
                {
                    _httpclient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
                    _httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
                    _httpclient.Timeout = timeout > 0 ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout) : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60000);
                    Insights.Track("ApiUrlCalled", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Api URL", url } });
                    var jsonOut = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, new IsoDateTimeConverter()));
                    jsonOut.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpclient.PostAsync(url, jsonOut);
                    switch (response.StatusCode)
                    {
                        case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
                            ReceiveNotificationDateTime(result);
                            return result;
                        default:
                            var result1 = new T { StatusID = (int)SystemStatusOutcomes.Failed, StatusMessage = response.ToString() };
                            ReceiveNotificationDateTime(result1);
                            return result1;
                    }
                }
```

It's worth noting that the app when talking to the production api works fine on all devices. And we're also able to make post requests to the dev api via Postman.

After some digging and scratching, I found out that the ciphers used on production and dev were different.

Here's the cipher used on Prod [image: Production Cipher]
and here's the one used on dev[image: Dev Cipher].

I had a look at the SSL Ciphers Android supports [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html). And it looks like the ciper suite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 is supported in Android Api version 20+. This makes sense that it wont work on Android 4.4. But why would we get this error on Nexus 5? Any pointers?

Also is there any workaround to get this cipher enabled on Android 4.4?

Comment: What does the webserver log contain for those connection attempts?

Comment: Good question, never considered that. Let me check.....

Comment: I checked the IIS logs located here C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC3. And even though I was redirected to the error screen on the app there were no entries in the log :(

Comment: I tried with the Samsung Galaxy A7 and I could see this in the logs
2017-09-21 04:29:31 192.168.1.69 POST /CustomerAppApiCore/api/Definitions/GetMinimumVersion - 443 - 192.168.1.232 Dalvik/2.1.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+6.0.1;+SM-A720F+Build/MMB29K) - 200 0 0 12609
2017-09-21 04:29:31 192.168.1.69 POST /CustomerAppApiCore/api/Definitions/SysRefDataDefinitions - 443 - 192.168.1.232 Dalvik/2.1.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+6.0.1;+SM-A720F+Build/MMB29K) - 200 0 0 624

Comment: You might be able to use bouncy castle to add that suite for Android API <20, but `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` is included in Server2016/Win10 and is supported by `SCH_USE_STRONG_CRYPTO` and is an accepted suite on PCI's list (review their 2017 technical FAQs), I would enable it on those dev servers (via gpedit.msc) within the `SSL Cipher Suite Order`. (I would *assume* someone disabled it as it (and other suites) are supported on TLS1.0/1.1, but enabling it does not mean you are enabling 1.0/1.1.....

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you for the feedback. I am not a 100% sure why the IT team decided to install this cipher suite, but we are in parallel talking to the auditors just to make sure. If they say they're happy with TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA all of this will just go away :)

Comment: @SushiHangover The IT team enabled the ciphers sobits working now. If you could add an answer on how to use bouncy castle I'll accept it as an answer